# How workaround this ModuleNotFoundError error that only occurs in the WebbPSF environment?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

I am trying to run a code I downloaded from https://github.com/szieleniewski/NIFSIM to analyze data from JWSTelescope. While running the main file, jwsim.py, I get a module error on one of the definitions.

I am currently using Python 3.7, Ubuntu 16.04, and I work under an environment (called webbpsf-env). These details can not be changed, since WebbPSF (a program I am using with the code) requires such versions to work. The main jsim.py file is stored in the Downloads folder.

I get the following error:

```
(webbpsf-env) aleejandrof@aleejandrof-Satellite-C55t-B:~/Downloads/NIFSIM-master$ python jsim.py
  *File* "jsim.py", line 18, in <module>
    *from* src.JSIM_main *import* main
  File "/home/aleejandrof/Downloads/NIFSIM-master/src/JSIM_main.py", line 22, in <module>
    *from* JSIM_Specres *import* spectral_res
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'JSIM_Specres'
```

The mentioned line is this one:

```
from JSIM_Specres import spectral_res
```

I've been told, that if I work ouside the environment, the module could be found. For me this is not an option since Webbpsf requires working inside an environment. I have tried downloading the master file again inside the environment (through pip), but it could not be done. Is there a way to "insert" a file into an environment? what should I do?

Comment: You need to `pip install` whichever package has `JSIM_Specres` in your virtualenv.

Comment: i would suggest you to refactor the code and improve import statement (eg  in the file JSIN_Specres  use `from .JSIM_Specres import spectral_res`

Answer (score 0):

The author likely anticipated you had a certain env var set. Try this:

```
$ cd ../NIFSIM-master && env PYTHONPATH=.:src python jsim.py
```